# Cocoa - Replicate mail button bar

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsbutton

How do I replicate the appearance of the button bar in the Mail App? I'm pretty close, but I cannot seem to get the colors to work the way I want.

If I set the background color for the view containing the buttons, it won't look the same as the NSTableView above it when the window loses focus.

**Here is my app with focus:**

[image: My App with focus]

**My app without focus:**

[image: My App without focus]

**Mail.app with focus:**

[image: Mail app with focus]

**Mail.app without focus:**

[image: Mail app without focus]

So in short, I want the same behaviour as the mail button bar with or without focus. How would one do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a lot of time on this and then after finally asks a question here, I manage to fix it.

What I did was adding a bottom bar in IB and then programmatically setting the same color on the bottom bar as the background color on the NSTableView.